# Having difficulty creating a responsive navigation menu with sub menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a navigation menu bar that works really well.

I want to make it responsive and have been able to adjust my code through javascript and css to use a list icon that appears shown when the screen size gets below 680px threshold. There appears to be a few problems with the code when I view the menu on a mobile device as well as formatting problems for viewing on smaller screens.

1: The list icon will hide behind the menu, which appears vertical on a mobile device. Its hard to click on, but you CAN click it to reduce the menu back into the list icon.

2: The menu has several drop down menus with sub menus (Shown in the above picture) that double up on top of each other making it hard to click. This also causes mobile devices to "reload and focus to the top of the page, but with the sub menu opened."

3: The sub menus, if the text is too long, flow off the visual of the page, making it hard to read the entire link at times.

What I am trying to figure out to do is formatting the menu to be more contextual appealing when responsive. Meaning when the screen shrinks or is viewed on a smaller screen/mobile device, the menu changes formatting. The list icon drops down the main nav links, then each sub link drops the entire nav like the following image
[Example of Responsive Navigation Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFAlN.png)

I created a jsfiddle to help understand the code.
https://jsfiddle.net/rm2rL373/

```
<div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul id="myNavi" class="navi" style="font-size:16px; padding-top:5px;">
        <li class="icon">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SubNav1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">Sublink1</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">Sublink2</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">Sublink3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" >SubNav2</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">Sublink1</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">Sublink2</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">Sublink3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">SubNav3</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">Sublink1</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">Sublink2</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">Sublink3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">SubNavLink1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SubNav4</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">Sublink1</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">Sublink2</a></li>
                <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">Sublink3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">SubNavLink2</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">SubNavLink3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">SubNavLink1</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">SubNavLink2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="MenuBarItemSubmenu">SubNav1</a>
                <ul>
                      <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">SubNavLink1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">SubNavLink2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">SubNavLink3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav3</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">SubNavLink1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav4</a>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">SubNavLink1</a></li>
           <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">SubNavLink2</a></li>
           <li><a href="link.html" target="_blank">SubNavLink3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav {    
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  list-style: none;

}
.navi a {
  display:block; 
  background: #ededed; 
  color: #111; 
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.8em 1.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80%;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #E3E3E3;
  position: relative;

}
.navi{  
  vertical-align: top; 
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 
    1px -1px -1px 1px #000, 
    -1px 1px -1px 1px #fff, 
    0 0 6px 3px #fff;
  border-radius:6px;
}
.navi li {
  position: relative;
}
.navi > li { 
  float: left; 
  border-bottom: 4px #E3E3E3 solid; 
  margin-right: 1px; 
} 
.navi > li > a { 
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2em .33em -0.5em #E5E5E5; 

}
.navi > li:hover, 
.navi > li:hover > a { 
  border-bottom-color: blue;
}
.navi li:hover > a { 
  color:blue;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}
.navi > li:first-child { 
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;

} 
.navi > li:first-child > a { 
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
}
.navi > li:last-child { 
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 0; 
  margin-right: 0;
} 
.navi > li:last-child > a { 
  border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
}
.navi li li a { 
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.navi li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before { 
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute; 
  height: 0; 
  width: 0; 
  border: 5px solid transparent; 
  top: 50% ;
  right:5px; 

 }
 /*Submenu Position*/
.navi ul {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;

  z-index: 1;
  left: -99999em;

}
.navi > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  min-width: 100%;

}
.navi > li li:hover > ul { 
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  top: -1px;


}
/*Arrow Styling*/
.navi > li > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before { 
  border-top-color: #575757; 
}
.navi > li:hover > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 5px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom-color: blue; 
  margin-top:-5px
}
.navi li li > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {  
  border-left-color: #575757; 
  margin-top: -5px
}
.navi li li:hover > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 5px solid transparent; 
  border-right-color: blue;
  right: 10px; 
}
ul.navi li.icon {
    display: none;
}
/* When the screen is less than 680 pixels wide, hide all list items, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the list item that contains the link to open and close the nav (li.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.navi li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.navi li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the nav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the nav look good on small screens */
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.navi.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.navi.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.navi.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.navi.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNavi");
    if (x.className === "navi") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "navi";
    }
}
```

Comment: not a solution but first step is to make the sub menus position:relative for smaller devices

Comment: For some reason when you use the jsfiddle example and run it, it does not allow you to see the menu when the screen size shrinks. Least in my browser. On my project page the example works fine, but has errors showing the list icon after you click it.

Comment: @mike smith, I believe I already have this with the css .navi li { position:relative;}